# What affects thread scheduling in Java in Windows 7/8

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, scheduling

I'm testing out a multithreaded Java program. For debugging, I made the threads print out statements. The order of the print outs goes like this:

- Thread message 1
- Thread message 2
- Thread message 1
- Thread message 2

The problem is that on a certain machine it changes to:

- Thread message 1
- Thread message 1
- Thread message 2
- Thread message 2

The machine has the same version of Java as all the other machines I tested. At first I thought it was a Windows 8 issues, as the previous ones had Windows 7, but I tried it on another Windows 8 machine and it worked correctly. So my question is what other variables can affect the thread scheduling in Java? Just for reference the machine the incorrect sequence happens is a Acer Aspire E1-521-0694 AMD Dual Core E2-1800 with Windows 8.

Comment: It's not an 'issue' at all, as the execution order among threads of equal priority is undefined. If you want a specific ordering, it is up to you to obtain it, typically via synchronisation, semaphores, etc; or you can specify thread priority to give the system a *hint.* Without that, you can't have any expectations. If you really need a specific order, it's hard to see why you're using threads  at all.

Answer (score 7):

> the machine the incorrect sequence happens

When dealing with un-synchronized multithreading, there is no "incorrect" sequence.  Things will happen in the order that they happen in, period.  If you need to force things to happen in a specific order, you will need to add snychronization (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html for the Oracle tutorials).

For all intents and purposes, thread scheduling is totally unpredictable, believing otherwise will get you into a world of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that Java uses the operating system's threading implementation, there is no defined order in which the threads should run. This is exactly the reason why things like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition exist.

In fact, I wouldn't be surprised at all if you ran the program 100 times on the exact same machine, and each time the order changed. If you need to ensure that something happens *before* something else, then you need to add synchronization to your threads (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

It might also be worth noting that more or less the same thing is true whether you're using Java, or using pthreads from C, or whatever. Thread scheduling is generally undefined without some sort of sycnhronization code to force it to happen in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of posts and topics about this on [google](http://lass.cs.umass.edu/~shenoy/courses/fall01/labs/talab2.html), so I'm just going to summarize them.

You can try to schedule and prioritize threading as much as you want but at the end of the day the JVM can pretty do whatever it wants. So you can't really guarantee anything.

Answer (score 1):

Through threading, JVM only offers parallelism. There are no guarantees on any order. It's entirely up to the thread scheduler (through the *time-slicing* algorithm that it employs) to decide which thread should run and which should wait.

Forget about comparing the sequence over two different machines. The same JVM environment could run your program in entirely different sequences over multiple runs. It's simply incorrect for a program to depend on thread sequencing for its correctness.

To bring any semblance of order, the threads must communicate with each other through synchronization (using locks) and sometimes sharing a data object (that doubles up as a lock) to *wait()* and *notify()* on.

Setting *priorities* for threads is another way of influencing the scheduler. But, here too, different JVMs would give you different results. The degree of influence exerted would vary.

Answer (score 0):

The HotSpot JVM from Sun/Oracle maps Java threads to Operating System threads and your OS schedules them. Priorities can make a difference i.e. `Thread.setPriority` but gives no guarantees.

As others have said - you need to use synchronisation mechanisms to force orderings.